# C# generic class and overridden method

Tags: c#, class, generics, overriding

I have a method that I want to override:

```
public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
```

(Note: I cannot modify the superclass.) Anyway, in this overridden method I want to do:

```
return typeof(MyClass<T, I>).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
```

MyClass is abstract. I wrote it myself.

Intellisense underlines the generic part. So I have to make the method generic. But then the method signature is not compatible with the override.

What should I do?

EDIT:

MyClass:

```
MyClass<T,I> where T : MyClass<T,I>
```

EDIT 2:

The class that contains method:

```
public class ReferencesJsonConverter : JsonConverter
```

Do I need to add

```
<T,I>
```

to ReferencesJsonConverter? That is unfortunate, since the class is used like this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(ReferencesJsonConverter))]
public virtual WhateverClass whateverclass {get;set;}
```

T is WhateverClass...

I also have this method I need to override

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
```

I want to do:

```
var e = value as MyClass<T, I>;
```

in there. So I guess I really NEED to add

```
<T,I>
```

to the class itsself?

Comment: I think it Should Help you 


[Link 1][1]

[Link 2][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349227/c-sharp-abstract-generic-method
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9197384/overriding-abstract-generic-method-from-non-generic-class

Comment: It seems like `MyClass<T,I>` is not the type that contains `CanConvert`, since you mention a superclass. Can you show the declaration of the class that contains your override of `CanConvert`? Specifically, is that class generic with (at least) two type parameters called `T` and `I`?

Answer (score 0):

The following code is being compiled well:

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
    public virtual bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public abstract class MyClass<T,I> : MyBaseClass
    where T : MyClass<T,I>
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(MyClass<T, I>).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }
}
```

As you can see there is no need to make method `CanConvert` to be generic.

I assume the actual reason of error is something else you didn't mention in the question.